# my form is not being displayed properly

Tags: html, css

In the screenshot that I hvae shared you can spot a form, at it is clearly visible that the form is shown with a scrollbar(i.e. the form has a lot of content to be displayed). What I,m trying to achieve is simply display the whole of the form on the parent webapage. I have shared the html as well as css of the main page visible , so that you can look and suggest the edits needed to be made in order to do so.
[image]

This page's code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Control Panel
    </title>
    <script src="http://localhost:1211/js/main.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:1211/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php echo "USERNAME"?> 
        <span>
            <a  id = "log" href="">Logout</a>
        <span>
    </header>
    <hr>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" onclick="add()"><button>Add Record</button></a><br><br>
        <a href="#" onclick="update()"><button>Update</button><br><br></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="query()"><button>Perform Query</button></a>
    </nav>
    <section id="workarea">
    </section>
</body>
```

and its corresponding css is

```
header
{
 padding-left: 30px;
 display:inline;
}

hr
{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#log
{
  float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

nav
{
 float: left;
 padding-top: 100px;
 width: 20%;
 height: 500px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-width: 2px;
}

section
{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 100px;
 width: 78%;
 height: 500px;
}
```

Please suggest me the changes I need to make in order to display the form in the whole 'nav' tag area. Your help is really appreciated

Comment: No idea what you are trying to accomplish here... need to be a little clearer.

Comment: @Adjit made the changes , have a look if you are able to understand it now :)

Comment: Well you are setting a fixed height to `section` so of course it will be smaller. What happens if you get rid of that fixed height?

Comment: @Adjit just did that, no effect the form is displayed in the same manner.

Comment: And changing the height to something greater?

Comment: where is the form html?

Comment: @Adjit that doesn't seem to work as well

Comment: @khuderm when I click the add record button , the add() function is called which is located in my main.js. This function sets the content of the 'nav element of the html to the form that is being displayed. If you need me to upload the form's code, let me know . Ill upload it too.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out , for some reason the new object that was being created inside 'nav' has some problem in it , made the following changes in my css

```
section > object
{
  width : 70%;
  height: 950px;
 }
```

and it worked like a marvel :)